# Ordering data in Pandas dataframe by rule based on series

Tags: python, pandas

2 fast bowlers to start with,then two spinners,and then one fast bowler and the all rounder(Batsman + Bowler).The order within them will be decided by the number of wickets taken.

```
     Name             Role            run_scored  wickets_taken
19    P          Fast Bowler          62             13
18    Q          Spin Bowler          65             12
16    O          Fast Bowler          32              9
15    N  Batsman+Fast Bowler         114              8
14    K          Fast Bowler          24              7
13    T          Spin Bowler          17              6
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the dataframe

Comment: have you tried some way? Or do you have some idea so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort by wickets descending, create a dictionary mapping Role to a dataframe slice, and then concatenate results according to your rules.

```
# sort by 'wickets_taken'
df = df.sort_values('wickets_taken', ascending=False)

# group by 'Role'
g = dict(tuple(df.groupby('Role')))

# concatenate custom slices
res = pd.concat([g['FastBowler'].iloc[:2],
                 g['SpinBowler'],
                 g['FastBowler'].iloc[2:],
                 g['Batsman+FastBowler']],
                ignore_index=True)
```

**Result**

```
print(res)

  Name                Role  run_scored  wickets_taken
0    P          FastBowler          62             13
1    O          FastBowler          32              9
2    Q          SpinBowler          65             12
3    T          SpinBowler          17              6
4    K          FastBowler          24              7
5    N  Batsman+FastBowler         114              8
```

Comment: Thank you, i did conditional slicing so thought if a more efficient way can be  there.